# Count Function and IF Condition in (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT COUNT(Student_ID) AS 'StudentCount'
FROM CourseSemOne
WHERE Student_ID =1;
```

I want to add only two values for this `ID(Student_ID=1)`. If Admin adding more than two values for this ID then I want to show me a message "Sorry! you cannot add more than two values".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you need to tell us a little more. What is the problem with that query? It gives you the number of records in `CourseSemOne` that have an `Student_ID` of `1`. So everything alright? If it's more than one, show your message. Or if it's one while your "Admin" wants to add another one, show your message.

Comment: SQL is used to query your database. You cannot use it to show messages to your user and other UI tasks.

Comment: yes i know sir...for UI i use C# and backend i use SQL....now i have an issue...i want to insert only two rows for ID=1 ....how to restrict an ID in SQL ? @RenéVogt

Comment: CourseSemOne is a table name and Student_ID is Unique Culumn @Kake_Fisk

Comment: Constraint, or trigger.

Comment: if (StudentCount) <2 the 'Insert Query' else 'Message!You Cannot insert more than two' @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
create table student (id int)
go

insert into student (id)
select 1
union
select 2


declare @value int = 3

IF EXISTS
(
select 1
from student 
where id = @value
Group by id
having COUNT(id)  > 1
)
BEGIN
      RAISERROR( 'you cannot add more than two values',16,1);
      RETURN;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO student (ID)
     SELECT @value
END
```

Comment: Thanks Sir ,i am trying @bmsqldev

Comment: if your desired output is  throwing error when a value get inserted more than two times, then the above code is  correct. I have checked it in ms-sql 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent duplicate entries in the `Student_ID column` is to put a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` on that column.

The best way to have your application display the desired text whenever somebody tries to create a `duplicate` `Student_ID` is to catch the `constraint violation` error in your application, and display your custom error message instead.

Comment: i dnt ask for duplication sir ... @Tab

Comment: can you show the code you written with the table data?

Comment: public  int checkRecordForInsertion(int studentId)
        {
            int totalRecords = 0;
            string queryCheck = "select count(Student_ID) as countt from CourseSemOne Where Student_ID =" + studentId;
            totalRecords = DatabaseConnnectionClass.returnInt(queryCheck);
            return totalRecords;
        }
this is the Method for Counting the no.of entries for a single student.. @bmsqldev

Comment: int checkStdRecords = obj.checkRecordForInsertion(Convert.ToInt32(Student_ID));  
                if ( checkStdRecords >0 && checkStdRecords<5 && Student_ID =="1") 
                { 
                    obj.insertSemCourseOne(Student_ID, Course_Code, Course_Title, Total_Marks, Obtain_Marks, Grade, Value, Cr_Hours, Grade_Point, GPA, CGPA);
                    DatabaseConnnectionClass.UserMessage("Added"); 
                    Dataloaddd(); @bmsqldev

Comment: @EmAamir a thousand pardons, when two rows have the same value for Student_Id, I call that a "duplicate entry in the student_Id column."   What do you call it?   Because if that's not what you were asking about, then your question is completely unclear.

Comment: with respect sir here you are correct about your view...but not concern with my issue @TabAlleman

Comment: Then your question is unclear.   Can you explain more clearly your issue?

Comment: yes sir i can explain...i want to insert five subject data for a single student...i want to add only five subjects for a single student...not more than five subejcts....how i will restrict an ID through SQL and C#...@TabAlleman

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question.   The code in your original question doesn't mention subjects or the number 5 at all.   Maybe you should start over with a new question.